# Camera stops working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, camera

I have a USB camera and it's behaviour is really weird. I test it on the webcam testing website, and after giving priviliges to the website everything goes well, the camera works just fine. But I found out that after several refreshes of the website my camera just stops working (I can't see the output on my screen, earlier it was there). The only solution I managed to find is unplug & plug the USB again, then the whole thing repeats - camera works for a few website refreshes, then it stops again. Does somebody know what's happening? It seems really weird to me

EDIT: If it'd help, my camera model is "A4Tech Co., Ltd. A4tech FHD 1080P PC Camera".

EDIT 2: `journalctl` output:

when camera works:

```
apr 25 14:59:37 my-desktop-name firefox[2787]: gtk_widget_get_window: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed apr 25 14:59:37 my-desktop-name firefox[2787]: gtk_widget_get_window: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)'
```

when camera stops working:

```
apr 25 14:56:38 my-desktop-name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
```

also output from `ls -l /dev/video;id` (in my case /dev/video0)

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 04-29 17:39 /dev/video0
```

Comment: In a terminal window, watch `sudo journalctl -f` as you plug in your camera, until it fails. Also, [Edit] your Question,  and show us `ls -l /dev/video;id` when the camera is working and when it isn't.

Comment: hey, sorry i didn't see your answer, hope you still there :D i've been watching `journalctl` and i saw something - every time i refresh the testing website, 2 messages are flushed to the output:
`apr 25 14:59:37 my-desktop-name firefox[2787]: gtk_widget_get_window: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
apr 25 14:59:37 my-desktop-name firefox[2787]: gtk_widget_get_window: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed`

Comment: but when the camera stopped working, this came up:
`apr 25 14:56:38 my-desktop-name kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.`

when it comes to `ls -l /dev/video;id` nothing changes. do you know whats going on?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I have a possible answer, but maybe not. Rather than wasting time with an unhelpful answer, I asked you to show me `ls -l /dev/video;id`. Why haven't you?

Comment: sorry, now i did

Answer (score 1):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/video0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

You can check your current groups with `id`. Read `man id`.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: when I add myself to group "video" (stat -c "%G" $device) i get this output:
"User $USER is already a member of group "video""
does it mean that the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Read and execute the second half of my answer, following "there is one more step".

Comment: so did i, still nothing. I also discovered that using v4l2 library (simple programm that captures a photo from a camera and exits) camera works just fine several times when i run the programm until it freezes before "VIDIOC_DQBUF" ioctl, after killing the process and running it again the whole thing repeats until i unplug and plug again the camera...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Comment: No, this two-step process did not work for me and my built-in camera

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

try checking the hardware user privileges in User and Groups administration